# Aligning an image in an ImageView to the top-right corner

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview

There is the `ImageView` which has larger size than the image. How can I align the image in top-right (and bottom-left) corner of the control?

P.S. I know about the parameter `scaleType`. Its values `fitStart` and `fitEnd` are not suitable in this case, because they align image in opposite corners.

Comment: @KlingKlang it doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

`scaleType` cannot let you align view in top-right or bottom-left corner, but `layout_gravity` will.

```
...
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom" 
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"/>
</FrameLayout>
...
```

Change `layout_gravity` accordingly base on your needs:
bottom-left: start|bottom
top-right: top|end

It's simpler to use `layout_gravity` to align views. If you don't like, you can use ImageView & matrix this way:

```
private void alignTopRight(ImageView imageView)
{
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX); // !

    final int drawableWidth = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    final int viewWidth = imageView.getWidth();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postTranslate(viewWidth-drawableWidth, 0);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}

private void alignBottomLeft(ImageView imageView)
{
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX); // !

    final int drawableHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    final int viewHeight = imageView.getHeight();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postTranslate(0, viewHeight-drawableHeight);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

Comment: I don't need to align the `ImageView` control in the layout. I need to align the image inside `ImageView`.

Comment: @Stratocaster One more method added, you can align the image inside ImageView, but more code is required.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to not use an image view and make a custom view that does what you want.  That's pretty trivial.  Short of that, use scaletype matrix and create a matrix that translates and scales appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
image.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START
```

This is the easiest way to do it! Hope you find it well too

Comment: OP says *P.S. I know about the parameter scaleType. Its values fitStart and fitEnd are not suitable in this case, because they align image in opposite corners.*